# NullPointerException while trying to initialize a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, file-upload, nullpointerexception

I am getting a nullPointerException trying to add values from a text file to a 2d array. The first 2 values determine the rows and columns. Any ideas what is throwing it. Ignore the exception handling, and the print statements. I am trying to get the array initialized then will go back and beef it up a bit.

```
public Help(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException,
        InvalidFileFormatException {
    this.filename = filename;

    System.out.println("Reading in file: " + filename);

    String number = "";
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
            row = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.next());
            col = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.next());
            System.out.println("Row : " + row);
            System.out.println("Col : " + col);
            baseMap = new double[row][col];
            System.out.println(baseMap[2][4]);
            for (int i = 0; i < baseMap.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < baseMap[i].length; j++){
                    baseMap[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
                }
            }
        }
System.out.println(baseMap[2][4]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

*OUTPUT*
Reading in file: sampleMap2.txt
Row : 5
Col : 5
0.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please add complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Which like is throwing the error?

Comment: For starters, use `Scanner#nextInt` instead of calling `Integer#parseInt` yourself; it's more readable, and you'll get a more informative exception if it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value do you expect to see here;

```
baseMap = new double[row][col];
System.out.println(baseMap[2][4]);
```

How about if row == 1?

Also what if there is no more data at:

```
baseMap[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
```

Maybe you just don't have enough data.

Comment: I was just seeing if it actually initialized a 0.0 at that position. It prints out 0.0 before throwing the exception.

Comment: so what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: It was a different method in a different class that was throwing the exception. I am terribly sorry for wasting your time, but do appreciate your help. It got me thinking and helped me find the fix.